# How to transform a list of Documents Snapshots to a list of objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to transform the list of documents snapshots to a list of UserData.

`updateUsers()` in the ViewModel should return a LiveData list of UserData.

So i use this and a repo to fetch all the users in a collection in firestore:

```
class ListUsersLiveData(private val query: Query)
    : LiveData<List<DocumentSnapshot?>>(), EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
      .....
      .....
      override fun onEvent(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
          val documents : List<DocumentSnapshot> = snapshot!!.documents
         postValue(documents)
   }
}
```

In the ViewModel(my UserData obejct has two Strings, name and phone):

```
fun updateUsers(): LiveData<List<UserData>> {
    val liveData = repo.getAllUsers() // return list of Documents Snapshots

    return Transformations.map(liveData, { snap: List<DocumentSnapshot?> ->
    //how do i transform the live data in the right way?
    //this is something i was trying but it doesnt work
    UserData(snap.get("name").toString(),snap.get("phone").toString())
    })
}
```

I can't fully understand how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Is there an error/  Does it do something other than what you expect?

Comment: the return in updateUsers() is underlined beacuse it requires a LiveData list of UserData and i dont know how to transform the list of documents snapshots that the repo gets into that, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the best way to do it because of the nested maps but i did it like this and works:

```
fun updateUsers(): LiveData<List<UserData>> {

    val liveData = repo.getAllUsers()
    return Transformations.map(liveData) { snap: List<DocumentSnapshot?> ->
            snap.map { user->
                UsuarioData(user!!.get("name").toString(),user.get("phone").toString())
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nesting maps isn't an issue.  The inner one is needed to transform each item of the input list to an output list.  The outer one is needed to convert the input LiveData into the output LiveData.